# What was the first commercial open-source software?

Tags: open-source, history

According to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) article on open-source, the philosophy of sharing code has been used in projects since the early computer days (mostly through Universities sharing code). However, I'm interested to know what (and when) was the first commercial open-source software (successfull or not)?

If there's any confusion on commercial, I define it as thus: "[Having profit as a chief aim](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/commercial)".

Comment: [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) was likely the first that set a reference on how to monetize OSS, with their [money versus time](http://buytaert.net/money-versus-time-in-open-source) approach

Comment: @gnat: I doubt that MySQL were the first. They might be the first ones with high-ish public visibility. I can think of at least [RedHat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat) that predate them. And there are *probably* much earlier examples.

Comment: @JoachimSauer good catch - as far as I can see, RH beats MySQL in terms of timing ('93 vs '95). And per my recollection, they were also first to set a reference - though it's hard to tell which project had better media coverage _back then_

Comment: @gnat: at the time RH had much larger visibility to me in IT press coverage, because each year people were constantly wondering whether that year was the year that linux was going to conquer the desktop from microsoft, and RH was the most likely player to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the good old days of Apple II and Commodore 64 and many others and before IBM PC, there were magazines which published source code of BASIC programs to be typed and run on these early computers. Customers paid the magazine and progammers got paid by the line of code.

I think this qualifies as commercial open source software, though I would not be so sure that this is the first example.

Comment: Was there any license information attached to the source code? If not, then it doesn't really qualify as open source.

Comment: I don't rembember the details but I am mostly certain that programmers who sent their code had to agree on specific terms of publication and customers had to agree on specific terms of use.

Comment: Yes, but did those "specific terms" comply with the FSD and the OSD?

Comment: @JörgWMittag - It was thirty years ago. Any resemblance to current standards is purely coincidental.

Comment: Yes, but that's what *open source* means. Personally, I am too young to have been a member of that particular scene, but I *did* start with the Amiga, where very similar distribution channels were equally commonplace. And those were definitely *not* open source. They didn't allow re-distribution. They didn't allow modification. They didn't allow *any* of the things in the FSD or OSD. They were proprietary software, just distributed on paper instead of on floppy disks.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting comments and the answer! I'll accept this as the answer, as it's indeed a very early (and not so known) form of commercial open-source software.